# how to remove specific buttons in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I remove specific buttons for example i have

```
<div>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
</div>
```

then i want to delete specific buttons in jquery,i tried use remove function like this

```
$('button').remove(2)
```

but it is not working do you know other options to resolve this proplem?

Comment: `$('button:nth-child(2)').remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) accepts an optional **selector**, not an index.

If you're trying to remove the 3rd button (index 2), try narrowing the selection using [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
$("button").eq(2).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha512-6ORWJX/LrnSjBzwefdNUyLCMTIsGoNP6NftMy2UAm1JBm6PRZCO1d7OHBStWpVFZLO+RerTvqX/Z9mBFfCJZ4A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
</div>
```

or for multiple consecutive indexes, use [.slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```js
$("button").slice(0, 2).remove() // remove the first two
```

---

If you're trying to remove the button with text content *"2"*, you can use the [:contains() selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) or use a more accurate [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
// $("button").remove(":contains(2)")

$("button").filter((index, el}) =>
  el.textContent.trim() === "2").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha512-6ORWJX/LrnSjBzwefdNUyLCMTIsGoNP6NftMy2UAm1JBm6PRZCO1d7OHBStWpVFZLO+RerTvqX/Z9mBFfCJZ4A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me please can i remove two elements immediately?

Comment: @Agata depends which buttons you want to match. Using `.filter()` gives you lots of options to narrow the set of matched elements

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [nth child selector](https://www.javatpoint.com/jquery-nth-child-selector)

```js
$("button:nth-child(2)").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: OP didn't say anything about removing specific buttons on click

Comment: @Phil my bad, I will update my answer, though you have answered already and Thank you for pointing out my mistake